# Apksigner without JRE?

Tags: android

Is there any way to sign an APK without JRE dependency?
Apksigner.jar is the only way?

Maybe a small .exe that does the job?

We need to build APKs dinamically at an uncontrolled for us environment, where requiring JRE could be an issue. Small dependencies is what we need. The other needed steps can be done with aapt.exe, and zipalign.exe. For signing step, only .jar we have found.

We have been searching for a while without results. Thanks in advance.

Jarsigner also requires JRE.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible by forking the apksigner [repository](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/apksig/) and modifying the project to build a native image with [GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/native-image/). The apksig project is Gradle based, there is a [Gradle plugin](https://www.graalvm.org/22.2/reference-manual/native-image/guides/use-native-image-gradle-plugin/) to build the native executable.